# Как в цикле for языка python внутри цикла перейти к следущему элементу внутри тела цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

мне нужно перейти к следущему элементу цикла for внутри тела цикла.

```
 for j in line:
        number_one=j
        # Уже следующее j ниже не то что выше 
        number_two=j
```

Comment: оператор `continue`?

Comment: Конкретизируйте задачу. Что вы пытаетесь на самом деле сделать? Возможно, вы не тот метод ищете, который вам на самом деле нужен. Ну то есть можно и в этих рамках сделать, но если знать задачу подробнее, возможно такие сложности и не нужны.

Comment: Обычно для такого делают итерацию не по элементам, а по индексам, по индексу i берете текущий элемент, по i+1 - следующий. Также можно использовать функцию [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) (добавлена начиная с Python 3.10), тогда просто делаете цикл `for number_one, number_two in pairwise(line):`

Comment: возможно пригодится enumerate()

Answer (score 0):

Ещё решение в лоб: запомните текущий элемент в переменной и в следующей итерации работайте с предыдущим элементом и с текущим элементом.

Comment: Скорее тут требуется проскочить итерацию и попасть после этого в следующий блок. Но на самом деле пока автор вопроса не пояснит, можно только гадать.

Answer (score -1):

Ну вот простейший пример "ручной" реализации цикла `for` с двумя элементами в одном теле цикла, в этом условном прмере, естественно, будет "потеря" при нечетном числе элементов:

```
it = iter('QWERTY')
try:
    while True:
        x, y = next(it), next(it)
        print(x, y)
except StopIteration:
   pass
```

Но это если очень надо, конечно, много практических решений приведено в комментариях к исходному посту.

Comment: Зачем же так костылить .. да еще с исключением .. да и не про while был вопрос, а про for

Comment: @Kromster потому что цикл `for` реально через исключение и работает. А предложите другой способ получить внутри цикла следующий элемент?

Comment: По классике - `for 0 to count - 2` `i1 = i, i2 = i+1`. Или если надо пройти по парам `for 0 to count / 2 - 1` `i1 = i*2, i2 = i*2+1`.

Comment: @Kromster да, если у Вас последовательность с индексом, то особых проблем нет. Если надо пройтись _всегда_ по соседним элементам, то тоже решения есть, а вот если следующий элемент внутри цикла нужен не всегда, но в сочетании с предыдущим (а не просто "continue"), то без итератора становится уже сложнее.

Comment: И вот тут уже вопросы к ТС, а что же именно он итерирует и зачем. Может быть он и вовсе пытается забить шуруп напильником ..